Is it always possible to do a Hohmann transfer orbit between two planets in a star system?
I’m curious if there are planets where the velocity at which they orbit around their sun and/or positions relative to each other are so badly aligned that it is impossible to do the Hohmann transfer orbit between them, or if given any two planets in a star system (for example, our solar system,) there's always a Hohmann transfer orbit. (That is, there's always a launch window.)

Regarding "Or if, given any two planets in a star system (eg Our Solar System), theres always a hohmann transfer orbit." No there isn't (a Hohmann transfer, that is). Just because a transfer orbit exists from one planet to another does not mean it is a Hohmann transfer. A Hohmann transfer is between two objects in coplanar circular orbits, period. Anything else is not a Hohmann transfer.

What you need to read about is a Lambert transfer, which is a solution to Lambert's problem. Other suggested reading is the term "pork chop plot". There is always one or more solutions to Lambert's problem, but some are rather suboptimal. A pork chop plot helps to ferret out the better solutions.

@DavidHammen ... "circular orbits, period. Anything else is not a Hohmann transfer" The Wikipedia article does not limit the definition to circular orbits, and identifies circular orbits as an ideal case.

@Woody -- That's wikipedia for ya, oftentimes oversimplified and oftentimes just plain wrong. Lambert had solved the generic problem of getting from point A at time a to getting to point b at time b (with $b>a$) in 1761. There was one thing Lambert's algorithm couldn't handle, which was a 180° transfer.. Walter 164 years later, Hohmann published a special case solution of a 180° transfer, which involved going from to coplanar circular orbits. Hohmann transfers are much easier to calculate than are Lambert transfers. (Continued)

@Woody I don't know why introductory texts call those transfers from Earth to Mars Hohmann transfers. They are not. They are Lambert transfers.

@DavidHammen ... It is nice to honor pioneers by correctly identifying their accomplishments. Its amazing that a mathematician can solve a problem centuries before the solution is needed.


Is it always possible to do a Hohmann transfer orbit between two planets in a star system?

No.
Hohmann transfers are from one circular orbit to another, and the original and target orbits must be coplanar to qualify the transfer as a Hohmann transfer. Hohmann transfers are always 180° transfers.
Hohmann transfers are easy to calculate, which is why the concept is introduced early on. Hohmann transfers are a type of two burn transfers: One instantaneous burn to change from the initial orbit to a transfer orbit, and another burn (or possibly atmospheric entry) on arrival at the target. There are much more generic two burn transfers; these are solutions to Lambert's problem. There is always one or more conic sections between any two points in space and time, separated by time, that serves as a transfer orbit from point A to point B. The amount of energy needed to transfer to or from that transfer orbit might be extremely excessive, but solutions always exist. (Lambert's problem assumes Newtonian mechanics, so some of those solutions involve faster than light travel. This is not a problem for Newtonian mechanics. Getting to such excessive speeds is a problem.)
Because one or more solutions always exist, this now becomes an optimization problem: Finding which of the infinitely many solutions to Lambert's problem (with different departure and arrival times) is "the best", i.e., the one that minimizes some cost metric.

I do see resources referring to earth-mars transfer as hohmann’s. https://science.nasa.gov/learn/basics-of-space-flight/chapter4-1/

@MinhHuynh It's pretty common to refer to Hohmann transfers in the Solar System even though the planets don't have circular, coplanar orbits. It understood that those are either in introductions to orbital mechanics to get people used to the idea of what "delta-v" is, or they are first approximations to get a rough idea of the total delta-v needed and duration of the transfer, a sort-of "back-of-the-envelope" estimate. But when it comes time for actual, precise mission design, the approximation is dropped and more detailed calculations are done.

@MinhHuynh transfer between Earth and Mars is a good example of a very non-Hohmann-like transfer because Mars' orbit is so eccentric you can't approximate it as a circle, and transfer between Earth and Neptune might be a good example of a near-Hohman-like transfer since both orbits are closer to circular and close to co-planer. Just like there are no actual Lagrange points proper, there are no Hohman transfer's proper, because both are mathematical simplifications.

@MinhHuynh It is so incredibly sad regarding how NASA has dumbed down their public facing web pages, beginning shortly after September 11, 2001, and continuing apace. The transfers between Earth and Mars are markedly non-Hohmann. The very concept of a Type I or Type II Hohmann transfer does not make sense as Hohmann transfers are always 180° transfers. Those Type I and Type II transfers are instead near optimal solutions to a Lambert targeting problem.

Why is there always a solution?  I can't picture an optimal burn from a body to a point within it's orbital path.  Your "optimal" burn will have zero energy and an infinite flight duration.  Say, Jovians sending a mission to the Trojan asteroids.

@LorenPechtel I should have stated in my discussions on Hohmann and Lambert transfers was that both assume a single central gravitational body. Transferring to an object in a pseudo-orbit about a planet's L4 or L5 points don't quite fit. That said, Lambert targeting is not necessarily energy optimal . The goal is to transfer from an original orbit at a specific time to a target orbit at a later point in time. It is still possible to compute the cost (which might be delta-v, C3, or some other metric) to accomplish this goal. Finally, going from a planet to its L4 or L5 point requires energy.

@DavidHammen I was just giving L4 and L5 as an illustration--doesn't matter if there is anything at either point, the fact remains that for a point in the same orbit you can always do it with less energy and more time.

An ideal Hohmann transfer does not affect orbital inclination at all, so it only works for transferring between co-planar orbits. You could not use a Hohmann transfer to move between planets whose orbits are at different inclinations. In practice, I'd expect the orbits of most objects within a solar system to be co-planar.
In terms of relative position, the only way planets can "keep their distance" is by having identical orbital period, which would be very unusual. If the periods are anything but identical, the relative phase between planets cannot remain constant - there will always be a phase at which the transfer is possible.
It's always possible to draw a Hohmann transfer orbit between any two co-planar orbits, and since the phase between planets with different periods is always changing, there's also always a launch timing that will work. If the bodies' orbits are not co-planar, it's still possible to transfer between them, but it would not be called a Hohmann transfer, which is by definition an elliptic transfer between co-planar orbits - a Hohmann transfer changes only the radius of an orbit.

Do you mean that, due to the sun’s gravity, it would be impossible to travel “up to” or “down to” another planet’s orbital plane?

@MinhHuynh Not at all - it's perfectly possible to perform an inclination-changing maneuver between different orbital planes. It's just that such a maneuver would not be called a Hohmann transfer, which is by definition an elliptic transfer between two co-planar orbits. A Hohmann transfer just changes the size of an orbit, not its inclination.

@NuclearHoagie A Hohmann transfer is not just a transfer between two co-planar orbits, but a transfer between two coplanar circular orbits.

@DavidHammen It wasn't clear to me if circularity is absolutely required to be considered a Hohmann transfer, or it just represents the ideal case. It's common to talk about a Hohmann transfer between Earth and Mars, despite neither of them having a perfectly circular orbit (although they are very close to it). You can possibly still transfer between coplanar non-circular orbits using the same steps as Hohmann (even if not ideally Hohmann), but getting to other inclinations just isn't possible with Hohmann maneuvers - I think coplanarity is in a way the bigger sticking point than circularity.

@NuclearHoagie While it is common to talk about a Hohmann transfer between Earth and Mars, those are never Hohmann transfers. It's  just people who don't know any better who describe those as Hohmann transfers. The transfers are instead Lambert transfers. Like Hohmann transfers, Lambert transfers are two burn transfers. Unlike Hohmann transfers, Lambert transfers are possible between any two orbits, with one exception: Lambert's problem cannot be solved as is for a 180° transfer. (Hohmann transfers are always 180° transfers.) Transfers from Earth to Mars are never 180° transfers.

Answer: NO
If one planet is orbiting prograde and the other retrograde, a Hohmann transfer is not possible even if the orbits are circular and coplanar.

It is also not possible if both planets have the same period. Without phase change, there would be no opportunity to time the departure window for the transfer.
Since a Hohmann transfer is a transfer between circular orbits with different radii, this example is, by definition, not a Hohmann transfer. If the definition is stretched to include elliptic orbits, a quasi-Hohmann transfer makes a bit more sense, but still isn't possible

I suspect there are other integer multiples of the period which would exclude a transfer departure as well

Well, kind of. You just have to accelerate retrograde instead of prograde at the perihelion in order to match the orbital speed of the retrograde planet. Accelerate a whole lot. But theoretically it is possible. Whether that still counts as a "Hohmann Transfer" is a matter of semantics.

I don't think resonance of orbital periods can preclude a launch window for reasonably circular orbits. Unless the periods are identical, one planet is always advancing or receding along its orbit relative to the other. It doesn't matter if one planet's period is exactly 2x or 3x or any integer multiple of the other, the only way planets can avoid changing relative phase is to have a fixed phase resulting from identical orbital periods. If the phase ever changes, it must go through every phase.

@NuclearHoagie ... valid reasoning !

@Philipp And there's also the fact that said huge burn is decidedly non-optimal.  By the admittedly simplified orbits of the Kerbals it's somewhere under 60 degrees of plane change where the "optimal" solution is to raise your apoapsis to the edge of the Hill Sphere and do your plane change out there.  I don't know how perfectly this corresponds to real world rockets but in practice we do sometimes go farther out to do plane changes--normally in launching to geosync from non-equitorial launch facilities.

@LorenPechtel Yes, a bi-elliptic transfer would probably be the more economic choice. But the question isn't asking if a Hohmann transfer is optimal, it asks if it is possible.
